# Result of `chcon` doesn't show up in `semanage fcontext --list`

Tags: selinux

Debugging an selinux issue related to Docker, I realized Docker didn't have the correct permissions to write to a host volume: /opt/var/games.  I ran this command to give the Docker agent the correct permissions:

`sudo chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /opt/var/games/`

This seems to work, but then when I try to check the list of file rules, that rule is not in there:

`sudo semanage fcontext --list | grep games | grep opt`

I would expect to see a rule mapping svirt_sandbox_file_t to /opt/var/games/ but it is not in there.  Should it be?  Do I misunderstand what `fcontext --list` is supposed to return?

Answer (score 0):

With `chcon` you change the label of files and directories manually. But the file context is not associated with an active policy-rule and could reverted by `restorecon` or by forced relabeling all files at reboot with `fixfiles`.

If you want a permanent label, you have to create a new policy-rule to set the file context (you have to install the SELinux-development package first):

```
cat opt-var-games.te
```

> policy_module(opt-var-games,0.0.1)

```
cat opt-var-games.fc
```

> /opt/var/games(/.*)?     gen_context(system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t,s0)

```
make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile
semodule -i opt-var-games.pp
```

Now test the new rule:

```
touch /opt/var/games/file
ls -lZ /opt/var/games/
```

> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:SystemLow    0 Aug 12 00:50 file

Ok, file context is missing, so restore it:

```
restorecon -vFR /opt/var/games/
```

> restorecon reset /opt/var/games/file context unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0->system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0

```
ls -lZ /opt/var/games/
```

> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:SystemLow 0 Aug 12 00:50 file

And finally check the file context as part of SELinux policy:

```
semanage fcontext --list | grep games | grep opt
```

> /opt/var/games(/.*)?                               all files          system_u:object_r:svirt_sandbox_file_t:s0